# Excel convert data to a range from 1-5

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I have two columns in Excel. First one has the name of my candidate second column gas values. I would like to convert those values in a scale of 1 to 5. How can I do that ?

```
Candidate1.    145
Candidate2.    75
Candidate 3.   105
```

Comment: Do you want ***1*** associated with the **highest** value or the **lowest** value ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not exactly clear whether you want to *scale* the candidates' "scores" to range from 0 to 5, or to assign each candidate an integer *rank* from 1 to 5.  I show how to do both below.

Suppose your data is in A2:B4 as shown:

[image]

To scale the scores, type this in C2 and fill down:

```
=5*B2/MAX(B$2:B$4)
```

Format column C to show as many decimal places as necessary.

To rank the scores, type this in D2 and fill down:

```
=RANK.EQ(B2,B$2:B$4,1)
```

If the highest score should have a rank of 1, change the 1 to 0 in the formula above.